# Fortran array element order in memory

Tags: fortran

I am using online IDE, and seems that none of them supports debugging. If I have a 4D array like below? How can I print all the elements of the array by the element's order in the memory?

```
Program Hello
    integer :: test(2,3,4,5), i1,i2,i3,i4, val;
    val = 0
    
    do i1=1,2
        do i2=1,3
            do i3=1,4
                do i4=1,5
                    test(i1, i2, i3, i4) = val
                    val = val +1
                end do
            end do
        end do
    end do

End Program Hello
```

Comment: I can't help you with the IDE  - but in Fortran this program doesn't access the elements  in the order they are stored in memory. It is also about the most inefficient way of ordering your memory access  - Fortran is column major, the `i1` loop should be the innermost for efficiency, then `i2`, `i3` and finally `i4`. This will access the array in memory order.

Comment: @IanBush This is not a real programme. The only purpose of this programme is for me to see how Fortran stores multi-dimensional array in memory. If someone could explain the order (for example, if it were C, the order would be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,....), I would not need this programme.

Comment: I understand this. My point is that this program has it the wrong way round - the order in memory is ( 1, 1, 1, 1 ), ( 2, 1, 1, 1 ), ( 3, 1, 1, 1 ) etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array/matrix memory in fortran is *column*-ordered, i.e. contiguous elements in memory are those of the leftmost dimension in your array.

You can print the whole one by just sending a `print` or `write` command of the whole array.

In this example, first we fill a 1D array with incremental indices; then, reshape them to a 4D array, so you can see how the 4D array items increment the leftmost dimension first:

```
program test_print
   use iso_fortran_env, only: output_unit
   implicit none

   integer :: test(2,3,4,5), global_index(2*3*4*5)
   integer :: i,j,k,l

   ! Fill 1D array with incremental values
   forall(i=1:size(global_index)) global_index(i) = i

   ! Reshape 1D array to 4D
   test = reshape(global_index,[2,3,4,5])

   ! Print whole array to screen
   ! Should print 1 2 3 4 5 6 7......
   print "(*(1x,i0))", test

   ! This is same as: 
   write(output_unit,"(*(1x,i0))") test

end program test_print
```

Comment: You seem to have rewrite my code to fill the array with alternating 1 and 2, whereas my code was filling them in incrementing numbers, 1,2,3,4,.... The thing I was trying to see was how each dimension is ordered so filling them with 1 and 2 defeats the purpose. I have tried adding only your printing lines (both of them) to my code on the online IDE, but they all failed to compile (Error: Expected comma in I/O list at (1) and Error: UNIT specification at (1) must be an INTEGER expression or a CHARACTER variable).

Comment: Then, your question is not "how to print elements in memory order", but rather "how to compute the unrolled element index of a 4D array". That's a pretty different thing, is it?

Comment: I gave up online IDE and installed gfortran on Linux and the printing like worked.

Answer (score 0):

After your attempt at loading the array then try:

```
Test2 = RESHAPE(Test,/120/)
Do I = 1, 120
WRITE… test2
```

That will reform the array into a linear vector or 1D array, and you can see how the contiguous array is stored.

Comment: I have tried your code in three online Fortran IDE's and they all failed to compile the reshape thing (Error: Syntax error in argument list at (1) main.f95:18:11:). Is there any online Fortran IDE that your code works or is there a way to make your code work on them?

Comment: You need to declare test2 or load it back into test (ie. INTEGER, DIMENSION(120)::  TEST2) … basically look up RESHAPE.